# Fonts' OpenType features not working in Composite fonts in InDesign

Tags: fonts, adobe-indesign, diacritics, opentype

When using any Hebrew font in InDesign, the diacritics (nikuds) are displayed in their correct location. This location is set within the fonts by using OpenType features such as `ccmp` (for glyph substitution) and `mark` (for glyph positioning). InDesign recognizes and applies these features.

The resulting text looks like that:
[image: non-composite font sample]

I put two guides to the right to indicate the end of text.

When this font is used as part of a Composite font in InDesign, the result is quite different. It seems like the `ccmp` feature is honored but the `mark` feature is not. (The first [last for non-Israelis] character on the first line is controlled with a `ccmp` feature to combine two characters.)

Here is how the composite font looks:
[image]

Notice how the diacritics shift and the length of the text increases. Some of this fluctuation can be mitigated by Diacritics Position feature in InDesign however this feature only works on a paragraph level and applies the correction to ALL diacritics uniformly whereas the whole point of the OpenType feature is to adjust diacritics on a character level.

Has anyone run into this problem and if so, is there something that can be done within the font or within InDesign to correct that (besides reporting it to Adobe who "will fix it in the next release")?

Comment: Can you clarify "used as part of a Composite font in InDesign"? The term "composite font" has a particular meaning in the OpenType spec, and that _shouldn't_ have any impact on the layout behaviour. But maybe you have a different sense of the term in mind.

Comment: @PeterConstable "Composite font" mainly within Adobe InDesign is a "virtual" font created by combining 2 (or more) different fonts under one name. I.e. base font can be Hebrew but Latin characters would be "borrowed" from a Latin font. This eliminates the need for excessive style nesting or creating *actual* fonts that would combine Hebrew and Latin. Composite fonts can't be used outside InDesign if they were created in InDesign.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In that case, it sounds like an InDesign bug. If you have ways to report that, you should do so.

Comment: As an Adobe InDesign question, you definitely want to ask this over on [the InDesign community forum](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign/ct-p/ct-indesign?&tabid=discussions), which is also looked at by the Adobe devs.